# Getting two values from one range

Tags: python, lambda, iterator

I have:

```
>>> se = iter(map(lambda x: (x, x + 1), range(5)))
>>> print("{:d} {:d}".format(*(next(se))))
0 1
```

The output is the expected one, but is there a nicer way to get it? For e.g. in a way that I get:

```
>>> print("{:d} {:d}".format(se))
    0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) instead of `map` + `lambda`:

```
>>> se = ((x, x+1) for x in range(5))
>>> next(se)
(0, 1)
>>> next(se)
(1, 2)
```

And, you can use indexing in format string:

```
>>> '{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format(next(se))
'0 1'
```

See [Format String syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

---

If you want to iterate over the iterator, you can use `for` statement with iterator unpacking:

```
>>> se = ((x, x+1) for x in range(5))
>>> for a, b in se:
...     print('{} {}'.format(a, b))
... 
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I was lost in being super-pythonic.